# Pip Install throws error code 1

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, jupyter, python-3.7

Recently switched from MacOSX to a ThinkPad with Windows 10.

Installed Python 3.7, Pip 9

Attempted `pip install jupyter` and received the following error:

> Command `python setup.py egg_info` failed with error code 1 in
>   `C:\Users\BRIANM~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-greiazb7\pywinpty\`

Uninstalled setup tools, upgraded setup tools, upgraded pip, ran as admin, all the traditional fixes are not working.

Anyone have a fix?

Comment: Is there a reason why you are using unstable `python 3.7 alpha`?

Comment: Good point, I could revert to 3.6, might be a better call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check that you have installed the 64-bit version of python and try again with

```
pip3 install jupyter notebook
```

If it still doesn't work than I would prefer you to use [Anaconda](https://www.anaconda.com/download/) it offers the easiest way to install, run and update libraries and packages and virtual environments for windows.

It comes with jupyter notebook pre-installed. On the jupyter notebook [doumentation](http://jupyter.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html) page they also recommend installing it using anaconda

Comment: pip3 also didn't work. 

I uninstalled my python package and used anaconda, worked just fine. Just not a huge fan of the anaconda distro, given that it uses its own shell

Comment: @BrianMauck just a sanity check, but are you sure you had the proper rights to install using pip/pip3? Did you use sudo?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and I found a solution that worked for me. Instead of `pip` I used: `py -m easy_install textract`

Comment: Can you elaborate?

Comment: Actually I wanted to install textract on python3. I tried : py -m pip install textract but I got the same error then I changed it to py -m easy_install textract and it worked. I know it's a simple solution but I'm new to python ...

Answer (score 0):

You should downgrade to python 3.6.5 (after trying all ways you can find on the Internet).

Today, I install python 3.7.0b5 on a new computer(windows 10). Then pip install didn't work with this error code 1. I tried all methods I can find on the Internet. And still stuck here. So I downgrade to 3.6.5 which works well on my mbp. Finally, it works!!!